# Mysql delete variables with underscore

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a lot of mysql function and procedures. And when I restore it from dump on my local machine - i have lost some variables.
For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `some_test_function`(`_some` INT(11)) RETURNS TINYINT(4) DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
begin
    declare result tinyint; 
    declare _some_second int;
    return result;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

"_some_variable" - disappeared. All variables which started from underscore was disappeared. Doesn't matter I'm used cli commands or phpmyadmin query. All expressions started from underscore deleted by mysql. So i got:

```
begin
    declare result tinyint; 
    declare  int;
    return result;
end
```

My db: 
- Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1 - Ubuntu 20.04 
 - Protocol version: 10

Comment: Can you check/add the part of the actual dump that contains that code? It sounds like something went wrong either while creating the dump or while restoring, so could you provide some details about the method you used for it? (E.g. mysqldump, phpmyadmin, sending the dump file with `<` to the mysql client, some script, ...)

Comment: i changed example, so you an try run. I have several dbservers - all work fine, but my new maria on clear ubuntu 20 have this ...

Comment: Sorry, my question was: what does your file (your dump) contains? If I understand correctly, you do: old database -> dump to file -> transfer file to new server -> import file to mariadb server. Somewhere in that chain, the variable gets lost. To pinpoint it, please check the content of the actual dump file. Also: can you create the function properly by hand, e.g. not via the dump file, on your mariadb server? If it works by hand, something in your dump process is bugged, if it doesn't, the server might be bugged. It works for me on 10.3.22, but I have no ubuntu 20 here to test.